# Uniqueness of the reduced echelon form - a doubt regarding the proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's take a look at [this](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Yuster19807.pdf) proof

It is claimed:

> It follows that both the $n$-th columns of $B$ and $C$ must contain leading 1's, for otherwise those columns would be free columns and we could arbitrarily choose the value of $x_n$.

I'm not convinced by this argument. As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345944/reduced-echelon-form-question), we can use variables which are not the pivot variables as our basic variables. So I'd say that the last column doesn't have to be a pivot column. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely correct (as per linked question) that, when reducing a matrix, you can pivot on any suitable column at each step and still get a reduced matrix with the same kinds of useful properties (e.g. column vectors corresponding to pivoted columns form the basis of a column space, proof of consistency/inconsistency etc).

But pivoting on these other columns gives a matrix that fails the definition of RRE form (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) and also the start of the cited paper). In particular, you end up with rows where the first non-zero element is not a 1. Note that in the linked question the author of the alternative pivoting example explains in a comment that it is not in RRE form.

I find the inductive proof in the paper you linked to tricky to follow, but then I don't recall having followed any other proofs.